# Pacman option to assume "yes" to every question?

Tags: arch-linux, apt, pacman

When installing software in debian systems we can put something like this:

`sudo apt-get install -y chromium-browser`

that way the installation occurs automatically, whitout asking to confirm installation [Y/n].
Can i do the same with pacman?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

From `man pacman`:

> --noconfirm
>            Bypass any and all “Are you sure?” messages. It’s not a good idea to do this unless you want to run pacman from a script.

Note the qualification about using this with care...

Arch is a rolling release, which means pacman has to, from time to time, manage some quite complex upgrades. At these times pacman will prompt you to confirm your choices—disregarding these prompts will generally not be a significant issue, but in some cases, as with the recent move from `/lib` to `/usr/lib` , a lack of attention will cause major breakage. This is a not a habit you want to cultivate.

Comment: I've never run pacman with the "--noconfirm" in about 3 years of using Arch, because of that warning.  How many people run pacman from a script?  What are the big risks? I have had to intervene 3 or 4 times to fix things that pacman has refused to upgrade.

Comment: I assume, given Arch's culture, that the warning is there to discourage complacency and the misguided notion that automating pacman updates is a good idea. A *lot* of breakage can be put down to people not reading pacman's output; `--noconfirm` would exacerbate that...

Comment: I have an "install" script that uses --noconfirm. The idea is to be able to take a system with a recently updated clean install and make it "usable" without any user interaction.

Comment: The idea is to install software from a script without any user interaction, so this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @jasonwryan - I have been trying to generate a silent server setup script for msys2 (future of msysgit) on Windows 8.  It emulates arch linux / pacman.  I've been unable to get `pacman -S --noconfirm --needed bash pacman pacman-mirrors msys2-runtime` to execute without prompting me if I want to install.  I'm curious if I'm doing something incorrect or if this is just a bug in the port?  Any ideas would be welcome...

Comment: @ColeChamberlain that command shouldn't generate a prompt.

Comment: @jasonwryan - Thanks for the response!  If I can figure it out maybe I'll submit a pull request to the project.

Comment: @JohannRamos I've done a script myself, to automatize the installing of an AUR helper. Besides using `--noconfirm`, I also used the `--needed` flag. That skips installing packages already installed and up to date. You might want to use that as well. EDIT: just noticed that cchamberlain used that flag in his line.

Comment: Actually, `--noconfirm` doesn't assume `yes`, instead it assumes the default answer, which is quite often `no`. Example:
```# pacman -Scc
Cache directory: /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
:: Do you want to remove ALL files from cache? [y/N]```
For the case above, `yes|pacman -Scc` assumes `yes`

Comment: Actually, `pacman --noconfirm` is required if you are using a Docker container, otherwise, it will just wait for an input, and thus shutting down the container with an error.

Comment: pamac has "--no-confirm" so it is not that easy to remember..

Comment: Actually, even `--noconfirm` will not work for certain conflicts, such as `Replace package with extra/package? [Y/n]`. Instead, it print `package conflicts can not be resolved with noconfirm, aborting`, then die with status 1.

Answer (score 65):

While the manpage on the matter is not very clear, the `--noconfirm` flag will not assume "yes" on every answer. It assumes the default answer which can be "no" sometimes.

> --noconfirm
>         Bypass any and all “Are you sure?” messages. It’s not a good idea
>         to do this unless you want to run pacman from a script

To assume "yes", you could pipe the output of the `yes` command to `pacman`.

```
yes | sudo pacman -S firefox
```

Comment: Use `yes | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 pacman [...]` for compatibility with systems whose language is not set to English. Otherwise the `[Y/n]` questions become `[J/n]`, for example.

Comment: Also beware this answer fails if Pacman ever asks a question without a `y` answer, e.g. `Enter a selection (default=all)`.

Comment: @ComFreek, rather than altering the environment variables passed to `pacman`, it would be easier, and probably safer to  just to do `yes J | sudo pacman -S firefox` in that case. `yes J` will cause `yes` to repeatidly output a `J` instead of a `y`.

Comment: "and probably safer" How so?  The override above only affects the environment
of the process (tree) spawned and ends with it.  Furthermore, the invocation
above is exactly the same for all locales.

Comment: Also, what if someone copy/pastes one such command line but has a locale in
which one of the options has the opposite or a completely different meaning?
Example: `J` (or `Y`) meaning "no" or "all".

Comment: Works fine in MSYS2 (Windows). 

Comment: @ComFreek you can go around an "Enter a selection" prompt by piping multiple commands one after another. Let's say you have 2 prompts for specifying which packages from a group to install; in that case you can use `(echo "1 2 6-5"; echo "3 4 8"; yes J) | sudo pacman -S kf5 kf5aids`

Comment: @ComFreek `yes ''` would output empty lines, so `yes '' | pacman ...` should select the default in any prompt and work in any locale.