# How to force pacman to answer yes to all questions?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am trying to run pacman from a script. The problem is that a package should be installed that conflicts and provides, but not replaces a currently installed package. As answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52277/79715) I passed the --noconfirm option and since pacman's stdin is not pointing to a tty it assumed the default answer which is no. How can I enforce pacman to answer yes to all questions? Please note that I can't pass any input to pacman (it's run via makechrootpkg) so I'm unable to use the `yes` command or similar as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202738/79715).

Here is the output of pacman:

```
loading packages...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: libinput-ubuntu and libinput are in conflict. Remove libinput? [y/N] 
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
```

Comment: If this is in a chroot, why do you have a conflict in the first place?

Comment: @HalosGhost I am installing some packages into the chroot and makechrootpkg doesn't install them at once but one after another; so the conflicting package gets installed due to a dependency of another one I pass via the -I flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be an option for achieving that, I looked into pacman source code and created a patch to add a `--yes` option to pacman: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/48835

Answer (score 8):

There is an undocumented option (`--ask BITMASK`) to invert the default answer (used in `pacman` tests). The following bit-enums are defined (`alpm.h`):

```
   typedef enum _alpm_question_type_t {
        ALPM_QUESTION_INSTALL_IGNOREPKG = (1 << 0),
        ALPM_QUESTION_REPLACE_PKG = (1 << 1),
        ALPM_QUESTION_CONFLICT_PKG = (1 << 2),
        ALPM_QUESTION_CORRUPTED_PKG = (1 << 3),
        ALPM_QUESTION_REMOVE_PKGS = (1 << 4),
        ALPM_QUESTION_SELECT_PROVIDER = (1 << 5),
        ALPM_QUESTION_IMPORT_KEY = (1 << 6)
    } alpm_question_type_t;
```

To automatically replace packages use:

```bsh
sudo pacman -S  PKGNAME  --ask 4
```